# How to turn Webpack ‘export xxx was not found in’ WARNING into ERROR?

Tags: javascript, webpack

file a.js

```
import {test} from 'b.js'
```

file b.js

```
export {
  tester
}
```

There is no test module was export in b.js.
Webpack mode is production.
Webpack build result is：

> WARNING in a.js
> export 'test' (imported as 'test') was not found in b.js

How to turn the WARNING information into ERROR information?
I want to know which Webpack configuration controls this output result.
Thank you.

Comment: export {test} and it will work, provided you have a variable 'test'

Comment: I know this writing is wrong, but my aim is when this writing happened, stop building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the configuration in module.

> module.exports = {
> module: {
> strictExportPresence: true,
> },
> };

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

change your webpack.config.js to

```
const config = {
   stats: {
    errors: true,
    warnings: false
  }
}
```

edit: according to https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/
try:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  stats: 'errors-only',
};
```

Comment: I tried but it not works, does any other options with here？